# What does it mean to "execute a command in an Xcode project"?

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

I'm reading [this](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/running-tests.md#prep-ios) setup documentation for Appium (iOS), and I'm a little confused at what they mean by "executing the following command in the Xcode project:" Do I have to run the command from the project directory, or do I actually have to use the Xcode program? Just typing in this command obviously doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a shell (terminal) command you can use (if you have installed the command line tools), so just open up a Terminal and paste the command in there.

Here is the man page for [xcodebuild command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)

Comment: I do have command line tools installed, this is the first thing I tried. I get `xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphonesimulator6.0" cannot be located.`

Comment: Navigate to `preferences` (xcode's one), then to `downloads` section and check if you have iOS 6.0 Simulator installed.

Comment: Or use `xcodebuild -showsdks` to get a list of available SDKs.

Comment: This did the trick thanks! I realized I only had 6.1 installed and not 6.0, I ran `xcodebuild` for 6.1 and it worked fine. I will mark as right answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

`xcodebuild` is a command line program, which should be run from inside your project directory - see [the man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html):

> To build an Xcode project, run `xcodebuild` from the directory containing your project (i.e. the
>   directory containing the projectname.xcodeproj package). If you have multiple projects in the this
>   directory you will need to use -project to indicate which project should be built.  By default,
>   `xcodebuild` builds the first target listed in the project, with the default build configuration. The
>   order of the targets is a property of the project and is the same for all users of the project.